# Hardhat Testing: Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from (operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION]

Tags: solidity, testing, chai

I'm having problems with my testing. I'm using hardhat and chai library.

Solidity contract:

```
function setMsg(string memory _message) public{
        message = _message;
    }
```

and my testing file is this:

```
 const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Private Messages Contract Testing...\n", function () {

    const setup = async () => {
        const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners()
        const Message = await ethers.getContractFactory("Message")
        const deployed = await Message.deploy()

        return {
            owner,
            addr1,
            addr2,
            deployed
        }
    }

   
   
    describe("Testing Message Functions\n", () => {
        it("Owner can set and get a new message", async () => {
          
            const { deployed, owner } = await setup();

           

            await deployed.setMessage(
                    "Hello from Owner!",
                    { from: owner.address}
                );

            const message = await deployed.viewMessage();
            expect(message).to.be.a('string').and.equal("Hello from Owner!");
            
        });
        
    });

   
    it("User can set and get a new message", async () => {

        const { deployed, owner, addr1 } = await setup();

        

        await deployed.setMessage(
            "Hello from User 1",
            { from: addr1.address }
        );

        let userMsg = await deployed.viewMessage();
        expect(userMsg).to.be.a('string').and.equal("Hello from User 1");


    })
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 await deployedContract.connect(addr1).setMessage("Hello from User 1");
```